# How to display a button at the bottom of a list in flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-layout

I am new at Flutter. Your advice would be super appreciated!

I am trying to display a button at the bottom of a screen after a listview.

When I enter this code...I can perfectly display my listview. Please note there is no button yet in this code.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: getTarotCards(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now, when I try to add in the Bottom Button which is a custom widget I made, I add in a column and a children widget so I can list the items I need to display.

I know that the problem is that the getTarotCards() is a method that returns a Listview so that's why I can't place it here (because I'm calling a function and not a widget.)

Does anyone know how I can call my method to display the listview and then display my button underneath this?

Right now when I run this card, my screen is blank and all I see is the black scaffold.

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make `shrinkWrap` (named parameter of ListView) to true in `ListView` if you are using `ListView` inside a `Column`